# In a Win8-Win7 dual boot, can Win7 boot from D:?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, partitioning, dualboot

The system is **dual booted**. First partition on the SSD contains **Windows 8.1** and the second partition holds **Windows 7 Pro**. Both were rescued from previous machines/disks which were, in various ways, dying. They were copied onto the SSdisk with a free partition software program. If you want, I'll tell you which. So, there has been no installing of any kind.

The situation:

- When I boot up Windows 8, it makes itself C:\ and the Windows 7 partition D:\
- When I boot up Windows 7, it makes itself C:\ and the Windows 8 partition, you guessed it, the D:\ partition.

What I am aiming for is that when I boot up Windows 7, it assigns it self to the D-partition, and Windows 8 to the C-partition. Just like it is when Windows 8 is booted up.

*What I tried:* After booting up in Windows 7, use DISKMGMT.MSC to change the C-drive letter to "D", which for obvious reasons didn't work.

The motivation for this setup is that the propiety software I need for my job, runs better if it's like that and saves time. I got no IT helpdesk to call. Reinstalling is not an option, because of licensing.

To be clear: Now, both OSes boot up, and all programs work. I did use a BCD editing softwareprog to make it so.

When I boot up,  I do get a **Windows 7** type of menu, not a fancy blue *graphicy* **Windows 8.0/8.1/10** type of menu.

Comment: I don't think you can, but is an interesting question if someone knows how.

Comment: I would be happy if I got mine to work that way, no matter which drive letter it uses. If you installed a Linux-type it would not matter to  the Linux which drive it was on either. I would just be happy with it and learn to like it. Peace.

Comment: eeeehm .... *bad word* .... but thanks for reply and vote, i guess,